# xxx shared a link via Widget Share Log App

Tags: facebook

I've created a Facebook App and am using the FB developer tools to share content on a site.

However, when a link is shared it is titled "xxx shared a link via Widget Share Log App". I've seen other sites change this to read something like "xxx shared a link via Irrawaddynews" and I wondered if it was possible to do the same here.

BTW, I'm initiating the Facebook SDK with the code below (as per the instructions here: ["shared a link via Widget Share Log App."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636183/shared-a-link-via-widget-share-log-app) - but this didn't solve my problem).

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{MY_APP_ID}',
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: Its just the app name that is displayed after `via`

Comment: I have a similar issue, but I don't plan to fix it soon - Facebook is just asking for too much work on my part to get it done. After you create your FB App and get the AppId, you need to get that App validated and in "active" status, so that you could use that appid, at least I think so. When I realized FB is going to make me create banners and privacy disclaimers for simple share a link button, I just left it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

In your App ID settings on Facebook, there are a few fields you have to update. We wrote pretty detailed setup instructions for doing this in conjunction with our own share software, but there's a general section beneath that for setting up the Facebook app:

https://naytev.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202777178-Link-Naytev-to-Your-Facebook-App

@userfuser - you actually don't need their validation, you simply need to make the app active. The process has a pretty terrible UX, and missing fields like "support email" will cause you to not be able to activate without a helpful error message.